# What does the additive assumption mean?

Tags: regression, linear-model, assumptions

The additive assumption means the effect of changes in a predictor on a response is independent of the effect(s) of changes in other predictor(s).

However, with regression, say, with one continuous predictor and a continuous response, the addition of an additional predictor variables can impact the relationship between a predictor and the response.

My naive interpretation of additivity would suggest that the addition of additional predictors does *not* change the relationship between, say, the first predictor and the response.

Why is this not the case? What exactly does the additive assumption mean?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're conflating two different concepts here.

## Additive effects in linear models

Linear regression assumes that the impact of different covariates is additive, so a simple linear model (for two predictors and a response) would look like this:

$$ y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon$$

As an example, let's say you changed the value of $x_2$ by adding 1, such that $\tilde{x}_2 = x_2 + 1$, then you would have:

$$ \begin{aligned} \tilde{y} &= \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 \tilde{x}_2 + \epsilon \\
&= \alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 (x_2 + 1) + \epsilon \\
&= (\alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon) + \beta_2 \\
&= y + \beta_2 \end{aligned}$$

So you can see pretty clearly, in a linear model, that it doesn't matter what value $x_1$ takes - the effect of an incremental change in $x_2$ is the same

## Adding additional predictors

This is very different from a situation where you were to add a new predictor **to your model**!  When you add a new predictor, it is quite possible that the other coefficients will change.

Answer (score 3):

When you add another predictor, you are building another model and this is likely to result in a change in the coefficients of existing predictors.

Additivity instead implies that for an existing model, the effect of a predictor on a response variable (whether it be linear or non-linear) is not affected by changes in other existing predictors.